# While updating wordpress getting Catchable fatal error:

Tags: wordpress

I have updated WordPress 4.8.1 to 4.8.3 then my website was not working. Hence I put back the backup I have taken. But I get the following error while adding posts.

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   WPSEO_Link_Watcher::save_post() must be an instance of WP_Post, null
>   given in
>   /home/physioca/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/links/class-link-watcher.php
>   on line 37

What do I need to do?

Comment: Hi there, i just moved the wordpress to iis and backedup db from linux host to windows. Than i took that error. When i looked into the database, i saw that "primary keys" and "auto increment" values etc. were not on windows-mysql. So maybe your problem is that too. Maybe your upgrade changed something on database. Please look to your table values and be sure that your keys are ok.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but here is my assumption.

In the following file:
public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/links/class-link-watcher.php

Edit LINE 37:

```
public function save_post( $post_id, WP_Post $post ) {
```

Should be:

```
public function save_post( $post_id, $post ) {
```